# Different one time contribution and recurring contribution on same contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

I know we can create a contribution page with a single amount and the user can choose to make it a one time payment or a recurring payment.

But... is it possible to have a one time contribution of, say, $50, and a recurring contribution of only $10 on the same contribution page?

Answer (score 3):

A great question, and before last week I would have said, no, it's better to create separate contribution pages for one-time vs. recurring contributions.

But then I saw how GiftTool does it (e.g. here: https://www.gifttool.com/donations/Donate?ID=1992&AID=1663) and realised you could do that in CiviCRM as well - it's just using a little javascript.

In other words, you could create all the payment amounts for both one-time and recurring on your form, and then use javascript to hide the options that aren't appropriate for the current recurrence/non-recurrence selection.

There would definitely be some assembly required, but it sounds like a worthwhile feature.